# What's the purpose of returning bool value in application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any)

Tags: ios, appdelegate

According to Apple's doc, implementation of `application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool`
 
need to return

> true if the delegate successfully handled the request or false if the
>   attempt to open the URL resource failed.

But it seems there's no difference if I always return `true` or `false`. So what's purpose of returning boolean value?

My app need to open a new page after receiving deep link. My implementation is

```
public func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    // Open new page here
    return true
}
```

But it seems it doesn't matter if I return true or false. That'w why I am wondering what the purpose of returning a boolean value in this method.

Comment: You need more context. For instance, what does **your** app do if it returns true or false?

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I don't use deep-linking and can't be of much help. Looking at this link (http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-deep-linking-in-swift/ ) it seems like the same as `application(didFiniahsLaunching:)` in that yes, it pretty much always returns true - maybe not to the OS - but rather like other `AppDelegate` methods it's meant to help you do "background setup" like launch your app or open a video stream *before* telling the calling app "hey, I'm up and running".

Comment: just making a guess but my first bet (guess) would be that returning false impacts the subsequent calls to delegate methods for UIApplicationDelegate. specifically the launch time delegate methods. that is just my guess though.